# Describe websocket api via Swagger

Tags: websocket, swagger

Is it possible to describe Websocket server api via Swagger?

We have events broadcasting via websocket server and i want to describe them via one swagger specification file.

Is there any documentation generators for websockets?

Answer (score 13):

It seems to be possible using [swagger-socket](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-socket).

Still, it seems that only a Java/Scala server implementation exists for now, which means they are not as much [*codegens*](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) for this that there is for "standard" Swagger REST services.

Edit: As pointed out, this project seems to be dead.
Unfortunately at the time of updating this answer, it does not seem that Swagger is a good tooling for type web-socket messages.

Comment: swagger-socket appears dead

Comment: @Charlie see my edited comment

Answer (score 3):

Not a documentation generator but this does do documentation of sockets

Firecamp - https://firecamp.io/ is like Postman but also does websocket and socketio connections. So you can document the socket connection there and export it in a collection same as we would with APIs in Postman.